# Angular 7 not working in docker ,npm install not proceeding

Tags: angular, docker, angular7

I followed the following steps

1. `ng new angularApp`
2. `npm start`   http://localhost:4000 working fine
3. Dockerfile

   ```
   FROM node:8

   RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

   WORKDIR /usr/src/app

   Copy dependency definitions
   COPY package.json /usr/src/app


   RUN npm install

   COPY . /usr/src/app
   Expose the port the app runs in
   EXPOSE 4200


   CMD ["npm", "start"]
   ```
4. I executed `docker build -t angular:dev .`

I am getting this output. Please help

```
Step 5/8 : RUN npm install
 ---> Running in 48d3519ff1f1
npm WARN deprecated circular-json@0.5.9: CircularJSON is in maintenance only, flatted is its successor.
```

Comment: I feel like npm’s error message (which is just a warning, *not a blocking error*) is pretty self explanatory. Have you tried replacing the deprecated `circular-json` package with `flatted` as suggested?

Comment: no i didnot tried that . Its taking too long for npm install in docker. Can you pls provide Dockerfile for " Angular in Docker ".Thanks

Comment: ”*It’s taking too long*” - does the command actually complete? If you want someone to write the Dockerfile for you, you’re in the wrong place. Having said that, 30 seconds of searching found [this demo repository](https://github.com/Ismaestro/angular7-example-app), complete with [Dockerfile](https://github.com/Ismaestro/angular7-example-app/blob/master/Dockerfile).

Comment: It doesnot complete ever .  If anyone has ever done angular7 setup in docker and got it working  , please provide me link for git repo or just the dockerfile been used. Thanks for the link @MTCoster